# How to integrate Hadoop of Oracle Bigdata Appliance into Ab Initio Metadata Hub?

Tags: cloudera-cdh, ab-initio

I am trying to integrate Hadoop of Oracle Bigdata Appliance into Ab Initio Metadata Hub. I want to know whether I can integrate or not? I didn`t find any documentary that relate to integration.